# How to upload python object(data) into impala(hadoop cluster)?

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, impala

I have data in hadoop cluster. I pulled it in python jupyter by establishing ODBC connection and using pyodbc library. I done analysis and results, I have to upload to hadoop cluster creating new table. Please help me.

tried with `from sqlalchemy import create_engine` and create_engine.

It is throwing error message

> 'Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:hive'.

Tried after importing dialects but got the same error. Thanks in advance

```
host = 'raghavs@PRD.SUTH.COM' #eu2azedno04.prd.suth.com
port = 21050
schema = 'analyticsworkbench'
table = 'test'
engine = create_engine('hive://raghavs@eu2azedno04.prd.suth.com/analyticsworkbench/test')
```

Comment: I would recommend you to go through the answers in the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370431/how-to-access-hive-via-python

Comment: @JimTodd. I have already established connection with hadoop(impala) and imported data into python environment and done some analysis on that. Now I have to upload result data(python object) back to hadoop cluster. The link you shared contains details how to connected to hadoop custer and read data into python environment which I already done. Please help to upload back data(Python object) to hadoop cluster.

Comment: You can store the output to a file, and upload to HDFS using hdfs commands.

Comment: I have to put the data in production and where manual intervention will not be there. So I cant download data locally and upload to HDFS. I have tried this way: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597662/inserting-a-python-dataframe-into-hive-from-an-external-server). Getting error as stated above.

Comment: Please help me out with solution...