# How to load the excel data into hive using python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a python scripts to load the multiple excel sheet data into hive table using python. Any one helping on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can read excels using pandas and insert the dataframe using pyhive or any other Hive library.

[Inserting a Python Dataframe into Hive from an external server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597662/inserting-a-python-dataframe-into-hive-from-an-external-server)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very easy!!
You should have pandas library installed or install it using pip if you don't have by typing this in the command prompt -     py -m pip install pandas

Then, use the following code -

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('', '')

print(df)

You will see that the table is available in excel.